# Issue in the popdown box (QComboBox) in QGIS 2.6 Python plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7, pyqt

I had developed a plugin that counts the number of features for a layer in Qgis2.6. When i load a layer say 'Airport' for first time and click the pop-down box in the plugin,it lists the airport once.The issue is that if i close the plugin and once again if i use the plugin and expand the pop-down box i can see the layer 'Airport' is listed twice.Sorry that i couldn't able to take a snap of the pop-down box.I think it may be due to some memory issue.But figuring out the exact issue may help me a lot.I had attached the overall appearance of my plugin.
Is there any way to clear the items in the combo box?Hope that helps.

```
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsMapLayer
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QIcon, QMessageBox
# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
import resources_rc
# Import the code for the dialog
from featurecount_dialog import FeatureCountDialog
import os.path


class FeatureCount:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'FeatureCount_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)

            if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Create the dialog (after translation) and keep reference
        self.dlg = FeatureCountDialog()

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&FeatureCount')
        # TODO: We are going to let the user set this up in a future iteration
        self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'FeatureCount')
        self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'FeatureCount')

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

        We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

        :param message: String for translation.
        :type message: str, QString

        :returns: Translated version of message.
        :rtype: QString
        """
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('FeatureCount', message)


    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
        """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

        :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
            path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
        :type icon_path: str

        :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
        :type text: str

        :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
        :type callback: function

        :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
            by default. Defaults to True.
        :type enabled_flag: bool

        :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_menu: bool

        :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_toolbar: bool

        :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
            hovers over the action.
        :type status_tip: str

        :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
        :type parent: QWidget

        :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
            mouse pointer hovers over the action.

        :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
            added to self.actions list.
        :rtype: QAction
        """

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            self.toolbar.addAction(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = ':/plugins/FeatureCount/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u'FeatureCount'),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())


    def unload(self):
        """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&FeatureCount'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)


    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()

        layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()
        for layer in layers:
            if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
                self.dlg.featurecombo.addItem( layer.name(), layer )
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result  == 1:
            index = self.dlg.featurecombo.currentIndex()
            layer = self.dlg.featurecombo.itemData(index)
            if layer > 0:
                QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(),"feature count","%s has %d features." %(layer.name(),layer.featureCount()))
            else:
                QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(),"Warning!",'Touch me after loading a layer!')
                # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
                # substitute with your code.
                pass
```

[image]

Comment: Need to see code to help you with this?

Comment: Please find the code above

Comment: It is done already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear a `QComboBox` by calling its `clear()` method.

In your case, it would make sense to edit the `run()` method, so that every time the user launches the plugin (for example, by clicking the plugin's main button), the `QComboBox` is cleared before layers are added to it:

```
def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()

    # Clear the QComboBox before loading layers
    self.dlg.featurecombo.clear()    

    layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()
    for layer in layers:
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
            self.dlg.featurecombo.addItem( layer.name(), layer )
```

Comment: Thank you so much. your solution solved my other problem in the link too gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128284/

Answer (score 1):

Try to move the below part of the code from the **run** to the **initGui** function.

```
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()
for layer in layers:
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
        self.dlg.featurecombo.addItem( layer.name(), layer )
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.But,if i move the above code from run to initGui, the popdown box is not listing the layer at all though layers are present.